# Install Loki in Monolithic filesystem mode with helm

Tags: grafana-loki

How can I install Loki in the `Monolithic` (single binary) [deployment mode](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/fundamentals/architecture/deployment-modes/) running on a local filesystem?

I use the values which I found in the [upgrading section of the docs](https://github.com/grafana/loki/tree/main/production/helm/loki) and call a simple `helm install`:

```
helm install loki grafana/loki --values values.yaml --namespace loki --create-namespace
```

values.yaml

```
loki:
  commonConfig:
    replication_factor: 1
  storage:
    type: 'filesystem'
```

Now only a single loki instance is started, but it crashes with an error:

```
invalid ruler config: invalid ruler store config: invalid Azure Storage config: unsupported Azure blob storage environment: , please select one of:  AzureGlobal, AzureChinaCloud, AzureGermanCloud, AzureUSGovernment
```

Why does it try to use an Azure storage although I've configured `filesystem` as `storage type`?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to also provide a `rulerConfig`:

So the full values.yaml looks like this:

```
loki:
  commonConfig:
    replication_factor: 1
  storage:
    type: 'filesystem'
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: "/var/loki/chunks"
      rules_directory: "/var/loki/rules"

  rulerConfig:
    storage:
      type: local
```

I've found the solution here: https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/7267#issuecomment-1260579364